# How to create a multi-objective model with objective priority

Tags: cplex, opl

I'm trying to solve a multi-objective problem in which I have to minimize two different objectives but with one taking priority over the other one.

To solve the problem, and hence the question, I tried to use weighted sum of both objective functions. The problem here is that that approach finds the minimum value between the two problems which I don't want. I want to solve one objective and then, maintaning that specific value, I want to solve the other problem.

Comment: An answer below is essentially "link only". I am preserving [the link here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=abac189a-0b99-4a08-bedf-78bbf919e14d) in case it is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 12.9 of CPLEX has the ability to do exactly that: solve one objective, fix its value, and move to the next objective.  Here's an example LP:

```
Maximize multi-objectives
first: abstol=2
   x1
second: priority=-1
   x2
Subject to
   x1 + x2 = 10
General
   x1 x2
End
```

This feature is described in [the release notes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/Optimization_Studio/topics/COS_relnotes_intro.html), as well as in [these slides](https://fr.slideshare.net/xnodet/cplex-129-multiobjective).

Answer (score 1):

You could use staticLex.

```
int nbKids=200;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
float costBus50=625;

dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ nbBus50;

dvar float cost;
dvar float co2emission;

minimize
  staticLex(cost,co2emission);

subject to
{
 cost==costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
 co2emission==nbBus50+nbBus40*1.1+nbBus30*1.2;

  40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The minimum cost is ",cost);
  writeln("CO2 emission is ",co2emission);
  writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses ",nbBus30,
  " 30 seats buses and ", nbBus50," buses 50 seats");
}
```

which gives

```
The minimum cost is 2500
CO2 emission is 4
We will use 0 40 seats buses 0 30 seats buses and 4 buses 50 seats
```

I posted this answer 5 days ago but that was deleted by a moderator.

See tiny example at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=abac189a-0b99-4a08-bedf-78bbf919e14d